# why i always get "false" in my code

Tags: c++

I wrote code to check the input, I set the `HavePunct` flag always `false`. However when I input `hello,world!!` it returns the wrong results to me. Please let me know if you see any problems with my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s,result_s;
    char ch;
    bool HavePunct = false;
    int sLen = s.size();

    cout << "Enter a string:" << endl;
    getline(cin, s);
        //检测字符串是否有符号
    for (string::size_type i = 0;i != sLen; ++i) {
        ch = s[i];
        if (ispunct(ch)) {
            HavePunct = true;
        }   
        else
            result_s += ch;
    }
    if (HavePunct) {
        cout << "Result:" << result_s;
    }
    else {
        cerr << "No punction in enter string!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping thought he debugger yet?

Comment: Look at where you set `sLen`.  Has the string been populated yet?

Answer (score 2):

You are computing the length of the line before you enter any input. Hence, `sLen` is always zero. Move that line so it is after the line where you read the input.

```
cout << "Enter a string:" << endl;
getline(cin, s);
int sLen = s.size();
```

Comment: thanks for your help sincerely.i don't realize this problem before.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot be sure, however it would seem because your iterator's upper bound is determined by the variable `sLen`, which you assign to be `s.size()` before you receive a string, therefore effectively making your upper bound 0 and causing your for loop never to execute.

Try this and let me know:

```
getline(cin, s);
int sLen = s.size();
for (string::size_type i = 0;i != sLen; ++i) {
ch = s[i];
if (ispunct(ch)) {
   HavePunct = true;
   }   
else
   result_s += ch;
}
```